# 100 GB SQL Server database stuck on "Restoring..." after restoring from backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I've restored lots of SQL Server databases before but none quite this large. I got a 100GB+ `.bak` file that I restored recently but has been stuck with this "restoring" flag for about a half hour now.

Will it eventually go away?

I checked my resource monitor and didn't see SQL Server pulling a lot of processing/memory so I'm worried something has stalled. I can't query data from it until it goes away I'm guessing, says the database is inaccessible.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please show the SQL command that you run the restore.

If you are doing this through SSMS, then click the "Script" button in the restore window.

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer on this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194863/12184700

```
RESTORE DATABASE <database name> WITH RECOVERY
```

The database still says restoring but I can now query it.

Comment: In SSMS object explorer select the Databases folder then refresh (blue circle arrow)

Comment: While you have your answer, it's good to know why this was necessary. However you issued the restore statement (I.e. GUI or tsql), it had the norecovery clause on it. That shows you too restore additional backups (i.e. differential, log) on top of the full restore. Only when you're done with all of the intended restores do you "restore with recovery".